# Do all Hindu sects believe that planets and eclipses affect day-to-day lives of humans and other lifeforms on Earth?

Tags: belief, karma, astrology, sects

A user of this site recently made this sweeping remark:

> > *Statement 1: Ancient Indians imagined some design patterns in sky which purportedly affect people on Earth.*
>
> Statement 1 can't be supported from any scripture because **all sects in hinduism believe in Jyotishya where Rasis and Grahas influence all Jivas on Earth**.

Is this really true?

Do **all** Hindu sects believe in astrology i.e., planets and eclipses influence the lives of humans and other species on Earth?

Comment: The basic premise of Jyotisha seems to have been topsy-turvy-ied. Planetary positions INDICATE your life path, not CAUSE it. It's like saying "Seismograph caused earthquake". If you sit in the middle of the road, and a truck runs over you, yes, of course the truck caused your demise. But the truck did not INTEND to run you over. It just does what a truck does. Your actions put your self in that position. When Gruhas "influence" your life, they do it from Agnya (order) of Bhagavan who ordained your birth based on your karma at a pre-determined planetary position/time.

Comment: Well almost all yes. Because Jyothisha is a Vedanga and also many many references to it is there in Puranas. So any Hindu who believes in Vedas and Puranas, which is almost every Hindu will to some extent believe in Astrology.

Comment: I already know most Hindus believe in it. I'm more interested in sects that don't take astrology seriously because I'm fact-checking a blanket statement. @MrGreenGold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Arya Samaj is the only sect which doesn't believe in astrological predictions.

> Eclipses and the like events are foretold with the help of Science of
> Astronomy and not of Astrology. Astronomy is a true science, while
> **Astrology, excepting in so far as it is relates to the natural influence of the planets such as the heat of the sun, coolness of the
> moon, is false.** By noting ht position of the earth and the moon that
> rotate in opposite directions to each other. (* the earth moves from
> west to east, whilst the moon from east to west) with the help of
> Astronomy, on can exactly know that at such and such time and such and
> such place there will be seen an eclipse of the part or whole of the
> sun or the moon. In the fourth verse of the th Chapter of Grahlaghva
> it is written that when the moon comes between the sun and the earth,
> an eclipse of the sun occurs whilst when the earth intervenes between
> the sun and moon , and eclipse of the moon follows. In other words, in
> the first case a shadow is cast upon the earth by the moon, and in the
> second case it is just the reverse.
>
> The sun being a luminous body no shadow can be cast on it. Just as in
> the case of the sun or a lamp various objects held in front of it cast
> their shadows in the opposite direction, so does it happen in the case
> of an eclipse. **The people are born rich or poor, princes or
> peasants, as the result of their past deeds, and not as that of the
> influence of the planets.** Many an astrologer marries his children in
> the most auspicious hour fixed according to the teachings of
> Astrology, and yet some of those marriages turn out to be unhappy.
>
> **Now why should such a thing take place and why should there by any widows or widowers (after such marriages), if astrology be a true
> science?** Hence it follows that one’s deeds (past and present) are
> the only factors in the causation of pleasure and pain to him and not
> the influence of stars. **It is strange that when the stars and the
> earth are situated in space so distant from each other that no
> relation whatever between them and man and his deeds can be
> demonstrated, how could stars influence human destiny?**
>
> **It is human soul that is the author of deeds and reaps the fruit of its acts. If, as you believe, the stars could shape the destiny of
> man, tell us, whether more than person is born at the same moment on
> this earth or not**. If you reply in the negative, you cannot be
> right, but if you say yes, why does not then one man become an Emperor

> [Satyaprakash Prakash Chapter 11](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-eleven/)

Comment: Arya Samaj is not a sect. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj) states it's a reform movement started by Dayanand Saraswati. A sect (Sampradaya) can't be created by a human being. It starts with God and flows through the various Guru Paramparas.

Comment: So, opinion of Arya Samaj is not the opinion of any Hindu sect but the personal opinion of Dayananda Saraswati.

Comment: I think it's very similar to Swami Vivekananda too who was against astrology for most part of his life except his last days when he was consulting Panjikas to select a "good time" to leave his body.

Comment: @Rickross but many hindus (non arya samajis) believe God and reject astrology? Also charvaka darshan :can this be called a sect.

Comment: Yes Charvakas are non believers of scriptures .. they don't believe in God or afterlife @Hope